# UDP server - when does it necessary to be multi threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

in what cases do I need to use treads when writing a UDP server in java and in what other cases it's not necessary ?

Answer (score 1):

You need threads when the requests are non-trivial.

For example, an echo or date or message-of-the-day server can produce the response practically instantaneously, so it doesn't need threads.

A DNS server on the other hand may have to delegate the request, and can't keep other clients waiting while it does so, so it would need threads, or `select(),` or async I/O.

Comment: is it necessary for Broadcasting to Multiple Recipients ? as in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: It has nothing to do with broadcasting, or sending in general. It is about how you process an inbound *request*.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need threads if you want to process **multiple client requests** at the same time i.e. high throughput. Let's say for each incoming UDP request, you need to access the database and send a signal to another service. This processing can take a long time and can **block** new requests, affecting performance, if you are doing it all in the same thread. With a multithreaded approach, each incoming `DatagramPacket` will be given to a thread as soon it is received which does the processing in parallel with other requests.